# Can I straight-swap my cassette 10 cog wheel with a ebike hub motor free wheel 7 cog wheel?

Tags: mountain-bike, cassette, electric-bike, freewheel

I have a Giant Anthem bike that has a 10-cog cassette wheel. And I have just purchased an e-bike hub motor that is a freewheel with seven cogs. Can I go ahead and fit it without any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would not be able to fit it without any problems.  Your Giant Anthem is using an 8/9/10 speed compatible freehub, and your shifters are also matched to the 10-speed cassette there.  Even if your e-bike hub motor with 7-cogs could physically fit your Anthem, you will not be able to make the 10-speed shifter work with the 7-speed hub.

If the e-bike hub could physically fit, you would need to change out your chain (a 10-speed chain is too narrow), your rear shifter (it may be difficult to impossible to find a 7-speed shifter that will match your front shifter), and your rear derailleur would also likely not be compatible (I don't recall if a 10 speed RD has the same cable pull ratio as a 7/8/9 pull ratio).

If it is a true 7-speed freehub, then you would not be able to mount your 10-speed cassette on it instead of the 7 speed cassette (a 7 speed freehub is too narrow).

Yes, there would be problems.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ted, for your reply. I suspected that it would be a problem with gears, etc. I knew I could not change over the cogs because they were very different, as the one on the free wheel is a screw kind and the other sits on splines. It is so frustrating that the supplier didn't say whether it was a free-wheel type or cassette type wheel. I have now boxed up the hub motor and other bits of kit to send back to the supplier, which will put me out of pocket for returning it as I didn't open the box until 10 days after purchase. Lesson learned.